# Make NSSavePanel forget the previous directory

Tags: macos, cocoa, appstore-sandbox, nssavepanel

`NSSavePanel` remembers the previous selected directory.

How can I make it to forget it, and restore the default value?

I'm working with a sandboxed app.

Comment: The default value *is* the last viewed directory. That is how open/save panels are designed to work. Why do you want something different?

Answer (score 2):

/*
To get a panel that starts by pointing at what OS X decides is the correct default
directory (absent a last saved one) delete any values saved in defaults before run the panel: 
*/

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:@"NSNavLastRootDirectory"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:@"NSNavLastCurrentDirectory"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

NSSavePanel *savePanel = [NSSavePanel savePanel];
```

/*
If you have deleted the defaults and you need to pass a value to a directory setting API and you want to get the "default" value, pass nil.  (But at certain times in the lifetime of a sandboxed open/save panel (after it has begun to run) you may not be allowed to change the directory anymore due to security concerns.)  If you do not delete the defaults saved values and you pass nil to a directory setting API, you will get the last used value.
*/

```
[savePanel setDirectoryURL:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

Call `setDirectoryURL:` every time.

```
NSSavePanel *savePanel = [NSSavePanel savePanel];

[savePanel setDirectoryURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:PATH]];
```

or

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:PATH forKey:@"NSNavLastRootDirectory"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

**EDIT**

```
NSSavePanel *savePanel = [NSSavePanel savePanel];

[savePanel setCanChooseFiles:NO];
[savePanel setCanChooseDirectories:YES];
if (mDefaultURL) { // memeber variable NSURL *mDefaultURL;
    [savePanel setDirectoryURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:mDefaultPath]];
}
//

[savePanel beginSheetModalForWindow:self.window completionHandler:^(NSInteger result) {
    if (result == NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton) {
        [self setBaseURL:[openPanel URL]];
        [self setupImagesMenu];
    }
}];
NSLog(@"%@", [savePanel directoryURL]);
if (mDefaultURL==nil) {
    mDefaultURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[[savePanel directoryURL] path]];
}
```

Comment: Same thing I told @FruityGeek. If I understand correctly, you're telling me how to do the opposite of what I want to do.

Comment: Store default path in member variable.

Comment: How do you get the default path, then (mDefaultURL)?

Comment: first time you will get [savePanel directoryURL] (default value).

Answer (score 0):

The first time you display the panel, store the `directoryURL` to a static variable. Use `setDirectoryURL` to use that directory for subsequent times you use save panel.

In a non-sandboxed app you can access the value through NSUserDefaults. You may still be able to. I know the NSSavePanel is replaced when called in a sandbox app and it may not set preferences in the same way (and may keep them in a domain you can't reach). You can open the plist file in ~/Library/Preferences/com.yourdomain.yourApp.plist to find the exact key.

```
NSSavePanel * savePanel = [[NSSavePanel alloc] init];
//store default directory prior to displaying save panel to user
NSURL * defaultDirectory = [savePanel directoryURL];

//Present to user, resetting default directory when done. 
[savePanel beginSheetModalForWindow:window
              completionHandler:^(NSInteger result) {
                          [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:defaultDirectory forKey:@"NSNavLastRootDirectory"];
                          [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
                      }];
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're telling me how to do the opposite of what I want to do. NSSavePanel remembers the last directory on its own. I want to reset this behaviour to the default value.